# UITextView not firing textViewDidChange on attribute change?

Tags: iphone, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` configured with a delegate.  I've enabled editing attributes by setting `allowsEditingTextAttributes` to `YES`.

When the user types a character in the text view, the delegate receives the  `textViewDidChange`: message.

But when the user changes an attribute (such as making a selection and tapping Bold or Italic), no `textViewDidChange`: message.

The documentation specifically says that `textViewDidChange`: should receive a message when the user changes attributes:

> Tells the delegate that the text or attributes in the specified text view were changed by the user.

But it's not working for me.  What am I missing here?

Comment: You are setting UITextViewDelegate Only...

Comment: Not sure what you're saying, Venkat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tested this scenario in iOS 6 and had the exact same outcome: attribute changes from the "select" pop-up did not trigger the  `textViewDidChange:` method.  It seems that this is a bug or the documentation needs to clarify what type of attribute change would trigger this event.

A possible workaround is to implement the `textViewDidChangeSelection:` method.  It gets called whenever a selection is made (which the user would have to do before changing an attribute).  Check to see if the selectedRange.length is > 0 (which would mean an actual word has been selected, instead of just moving the cursor around), and save that selectedRange.  Once the length is zero again, it means they deselected the item.  At that time, you could take the previous range and work with the text.

```
- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView
{
    static BOOL rangeSet = NO;
    static NSRange mySelectedRange;
    if( textView.selectedRange.length > 0 && !rangeSet )
    {
        mySelectedRange = textView.selectedRange;
        rangeSet = YES;
    }
    else if( textView.selectedRange.length == 0 && rangeSet)
    {
        // Work with text
        NSLog(@"Working with previously select text: %d, %d", mySelectedRange.location, mySelectedRange.length);
    }
}
```

Comment: It does seem like a bug doesn't it?  I'm going to file a radar.

Answer (score 3):

In [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html) it has also been mentioned that

```
This method is not called in response to programmatically initiated changes
```

So if you are setting bold or italic programatically so it will not invoke this delegate method

Comment: I'm not setting them programmatically - the user is setting them by tapping on the editing pop-up that the UITextView provides.

Answer (score 2):

Please check if you've set UITextViewDelegate in in your .h file. Also you'll have to `make

```
yourTextView.delegate = self
```

So that your Text View will give control to your current class.

Comment: It's definitely set.  As I mentioned, I am getting textViewDidChange: messages when the user types.  But when the user taps Bold, Italic or Underline in the editing pop-up, there is no message.

Answer (score 1):

I got around this by subclassing UITextView, overriding the `toggleBoldface:`, `toggleItalics:` and `toggleUnderline:` methods, and calling `[self.delegate textViewDidChange:self]` from those methods. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20233093/462162) helped me figure that out.