# How to disable pasting in a TextField in Swift?

Tags: swift, uitextfield, paste

I've got a `TextField` with a `numberPad` and the function runs only if it contains numbers.

The user will crash the app if they paste letters in the `TextField` and click OK.

How can I disable pasting in the `TextField`?

Comment: Don't disable it. Use the text field delegate methods to prevent the non-numbers from being pasted.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

I agree with [Leonardo Savio Dabus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29596238/7487335), if I were you I'd use string checking and just give out a warning, it makes things easier. BUT, if disabling paste option is a fancy feature you really want to put into your app, then you need to do more work. I'll provide the steps below.

Step 1: You need to create another class which extends the `UITextField`. In this example, I made my `CustomUITextField`.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit  //Don't forget this

class CustomUITextField: UITextField {
   override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        if action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.paste(_:)) {
            return false
        }
        return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
   }
}
```

Step 2: Wire the storyboard with your ViewController. You need to declare an `IBOutlet` as in normal case:

```
@IBOutlet var textFieldA: CustomUITextField?
```

Wire the circle next to the `@IBOutlet` to the `TextField` in the storyboard. THEN, this is important and easy to be ignored:

- Go to your storyboard
- Click the target `TextField`
- Select Identity Inspector (the 3rd one)
- Change the class to `CustomUITextField`

Quick snapshot is provided below.

[image]

That's it, hope this works.

**Credit:**

[Main reference](https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/disable-paste-in-uitextfielduitextview-swift)

If you want to know more about the behavior of `canPerformAction` method, though it's an Objective-C version, the concepts are shared [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20223966/how-can-i-detect-that-a-user-has-tapped-a-formatting-button-in-a-uimenucontrolle).

Comment: For swift3: class NoPasteUITextField: UITextField {

    override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        if action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.paste(_:)) {
            return false
        }
        return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
    }

}

Comment: Very important part is to return super canperformaction

Comment: **import Foundation** ... redundant., **import UIKit**  .... brings in Foundation

Answer (score 55):

For **Swift 3** it's changed to:

```
override public func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    if action == #selector(copy(_:)) || action == #selector(paste(_:)) {
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: Thanks perfect answer

Comment: What if I only want to disable cut option not everything?

Comment: @a4arpan Use one of these: "action == #selector(cut(_:))" or "action == #selector(cut)" or "action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.cut)"

Comment: Return "true" might create crash on some actions, please check all actions. @Andrey Gordeev

Comment: ```return true``` is incorrect, should be ```return super.canPerformAction...```

Answer (score 41):

For **Swift 5**

[`UIResponder​Standard​Edit​Actions`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiresponderstandardeditactions) has been added recently (iOS 10.0+) through which we can safely check if action is "paste" or not.

```
import UIKit

class NMTextField: UITextField {
    override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        if action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.paste(_:)) {
            return false
        }
        return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 27):

### Details

- Xcode 9.1, Swift 4
- Xcode 10.2 (10E125), 11.2 (11B52), Swift 5

### Solution 1

```
// class TextField: UITextField
extension UITextField {

    open override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        return action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.cut) || action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.copy)
    }
}
```

### Solution 1 usage

```
let textField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 120, width: 200, height: 50))
textField.borderStyle = .roundedRect
view.addSubview(textField)
```

### Solution 2

```
import UIKit

// MARK: Enable/Disable textfield longpress actions

enum ResponderStandardEditActions {
    case cut, copy, paste, select, selectAll, delete
    case makeTextWritingDirectionLeftToRight, makeTextWritingDirectionRightToLeft
    case toggleBoldface, toggleItalics, toggleUnderline
    case increaseSize, decreaseSize

    var selector: Selector {
        switch self {
            case .cut:
                return #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.cut)
            case .copy:
                return #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.copy)
            case .paste:
                return #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.paste)
            case .select:
                return #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.select)
            case .selectAll:
                return #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.selectAll)
            case .delete:
                return #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.delete)
            case .makeTextWritingDirectionLeftToRight:
                return #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.makeTextWritingDirectionLeftToRight)
            case .makeTextWritingDirectionRightToLeft:
                return #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.makeTextWritingDirectionRightToLeft)
            case .toggleBoldface:
                return #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.toggleBoldface)
            case .toggleItalics:
                return #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.toggleItalics)
            case .toggleUnderline:
                return #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.toggleUnderline)
            case .increaseSize:
                return #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.increaseSize)
            case .decreaseSize:
                return #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.decreaseSize)
        }
    }
}

class TextField: UITextField {

    private var editActions: [ResponderStandardEditActions: Bool]?
    private var filterEditActions: [ResponderStandardEditActions: Bool]?

    func setEditActions(only actions: [ResponderStandardEditActions]) {
        if self.editActions == nil { self.editActions = [:] }
        filterEditActions = nil
        actions.forEach { self.editActions?[$0] = true }
    }

    func addToCurrentEditActions(actions: [ResponderStandardEditActions]) {
        if self.filterEditActions == nil { self.filterEditActions = [:] }
        editActions = nil
        actions.forEach { self.filterEditActions?[$0] = true }
    }

    private func filterEditActions(actions: [ResponderStandardEditActions], allowed: Bool) {
        if self.filterEditActions == nil { self.filterEditActions = [:] }
        editActions = nil
        actions.forEach { self.filterEditActions?[$0] = allowed }
    }

    func filterEditActions(notAllowed: [ResponderStandardEditActions]) {
        filterEditActions(actions: notAllowed, allowed: false)
    }

    func resetEditActions() { editActions = nil }

    open override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        if let actions = editActions {
            for _action in actions where _action.key.selector == action { return _action.value }
            return false
        }

        if let actions = filterEditActions {
            for _action in actions where _action.key.selector == action { return _action.value }
        }

        return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
    }
}
```

### Solution 2 usage

```
let textField = TextField(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 200, height: 50))
textField.borderStyle = .roundedRect
view.addSubview(textField)
textField.setEditActions(only: [.copy, .cut, .paste])
//textField.filterEditActions(notAllowed: [.copy, .cut, .paste])
//textField.addToCurrentEditActions(actions: [.paste])
```

### Full sample of the solution 2

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addTextField(y: 50)
        addTextField(y: 100).setEditActions(only: [.copy, .cut, .paste])
        addTextField(y: 150).filterEditActions(notAllowed: [.copy, .cut, .paste])
    }

   @discardableResult func addTextField(y: CGFloat) -> TextField {
        let textField = TextField(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: y, width: 200, height: 34))
        textField.borderStyle = .roundedRect
        textField.text = "Text"
        view.addSubview(textField)
        return textField
    }
}
```

Comment: ```return action ==``` or ```return allowedActions...``` is incorrect, should be checking for condition and if true ```return super.canPerformAction...```

Comment: FYI I've downvoted this because Solution 1 is wrong. You can not override a class property using an extension. From the [docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Extensions.html) **_"Extensions can add new functionality to a type, but they can’t override existing functionality."_**

Answer (score 7):

Swift 4.1 this code is working fine with ViewController.

1) Disable all option (copy, paste, delete.....etc)

```
extension UITextField {

    open override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
}
```

2) Enable particular option (select, selectAll... etc)

```
extension UITextField {

open override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    return action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.select(_:)) || action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.selectAll(_:))
}
```

Comment: ```return action ==``` is incorrect, should be ```return super.canPerformAction...```

Comment: FYI I've downvoted this because you can not override a class property using an extension. From the docs **_"Extensions can add new functionality to a type, but they can’t override existing functionality."_** This method will never be called.

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 5**

If you want to block paste action from every text field in your app

```
extension UITextField {
    override open func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        return action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.paste(_:)) ?
            false : super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
    }
}
```

EDIT

If you want to block the paste action for text fields that have pickers as input view, add a `guard` like the following:

```
extension UITextField {
    override open func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        guard inputView != nil else { return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender) }

        return action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.paste(_:)) ?
            false : super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
    }
}
```

Warning: the second solution will allow the user to paste on numeric fields.

Comment: FYI I've downvoted this because you can not override a class property using an extension. From the docs **_"Extensions can add new functionality to a type, but they can’t override existing functionality."_** In other words. This method will never be called.

Answer (score 6):

You can just attach an IBAction to your Sent Events (editing changed) of your textfield to remove all non digits from your text as you type as follow:

```
@IBAction func editingChanged(_ textField: UITextField) {
    textField.text?.removeAll { !("0"..."9" ~= $0) }
}
```

This will allow the user to paste into the field but it will filter all non digits from the string.

Answer (score 6):

In the actual swift version(2.2 going to 3.0) this function code must be refactored to:

```
override public func canPerformAction(action: Selector, withSender sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    if action == #selector(NSObject.copy(_:)) || action == #selector(NSObject.paste(_:)) {
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: ```return true``` is incorrect, should be ```return super.canPerformAction...```

Answer (score 4):

```
class CustomUITextField: UITextField {
    override public func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        if action == #selector(cut(_:)) ||
           action == #selector(copy(_:)) ||  
           action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.paste(_:)) || 
           action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.select(_:)) || 
           action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.selectAll(_:)) || 
           action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.delete(_:)) ||  
           action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.makeTextWritingDirectionLeftToRight(_:)) ||  
           action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.makeTextWritingDirectionRightToLeft(_:)) || 
           action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.toggleBoldface(_:)) || 
           action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.toggleItalics(_:)) || 
           action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.toggleUnderline(_:)) || 
           action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.increaseSize(_:)) || 
           action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.decreaseSize(_:)) 
        {
             return false
        };
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: ```return true``` is incorrect, should be ```return super.canPerformAction...```

Answer (score 3):

You can create an extension for `UITextField` and override  `canPerformAction`:

```
override public func canPerformAction(action: Selector, withSender sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        return (action != "paste:") 
}
```

Comment: doesn't it disable paste in ALL textFields in app?

Comment: It does. It seemed to me that this was the intention. If not - my bad (but still an elegant way of doing this).

Comment: FYI I've downvoted this because you can not override a class property using an extension. From the docs **_"Extensions can add new functionality to a type, but they can’t override existing functionality."_**

Answer (score 2):

Small edit with a code because when you try to use any function like cut or another one the app will crash . The following code tested on swift 3 and working very well

```
override public func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        if action == #selector(copy(_:)) || action == #selector(paste(_:)) {
            return false
        }
        return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created a custom class for textField. I have handled the case when you want to enable/disable actions on textfield. You can customize the code as per your requirement. Set isActionsEnabled true/false for enable/disable actions on textfield.

Prefer to use

> return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)

instead of

> return true

because returning true might cause a crash in some cases.

Here is my code,

```
open class MyTextFieldEffect : UITextField {

    var isActionsEnabled = true {
        didSet {
            reloadInputViews()
        }
    }

override open func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        /* disable particular actions
        if (action == #selector(paste(_:)) || action == #selector(copy(_:)) || action == #selector(select(_:)) || action == #selector(cut(_:)) || action == #selector(delete(_:)) || action == #selector(replace(_:withText:))  || action == #selector(select(_:))  || action == #selector(selectAll(_:)) || action == #selector(insertText(_:)) || action == #selector(draw(_:))) && !isActionsEnabled {
            return false
        }
        return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
                                           */

       //disable all actions
        if !isActionsEnabled {
            return false
        }

        return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

iOS 17 introduces a new AutoFill feature located at the edit menu:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWRGW.png)

This feature allows users to insert unexpected data. But to disable this action is not enough just to override `canPerformAction` method. Even like this:

```
override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

*Solution:* Inside your `UITextField` subclass override another method called `buildMenu(with:)` and perform `builder.remove(menu: UIMenu.Identifier.autoFill)`.

```
override func buildMenu(with builder: UIMenuBuilder) {
    builder.remove(menu: UIMenu.Identifier.autoFill)
    super.buildMenu(with: builder)
}
```

*Note:* `UIMenu.Identifier.autoFill` - available starting from iOS 17.

So don't forget to add `if #available(iOS 17.0, *)`
if your iOS deployment version is lower.

```
override func buildMenu(with builder: UIMenuBuilder) {
    if #available(iOS 17.0, *) {
        builder.remove(menu: UIMenu.Identifier.autoFill)
    } else {
        builder.remove(menu: UIMenu.Identifier("com.apple.menu.autofill"))
    }
    super.buildMenu(with: builder)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to Open Date Picker or Picker view on TEXTFIELD click then below code work.**

Add below two methods in your class.

```
//Hide Menu View
override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {

    if YOURTEXTFIELD.isFirstResponder {
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            (sender as? UIMenuController)?.setMenuVisible(false, animated: false)
        })
        return false
    }

    return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
}
```

**//MUST Implement**

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
            return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did use this code. This is working.

```
override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?)  Bool {

    if YOURTEXTFIELD.isFirstResponder {
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            (sender as? UIMenuController)?.setMenuVisible(false, animated: false)
        })
        return false
    }

    return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
}
```

Comment: Downvote for: if user has a keyboard attached, user can still copy and paste

Answer (score 0):

if you want to disable pasting for a specific TextField you can use UITextFieldDelegate. Below code is working to find a specific TextField and stop pasting.

```
class TextClass: UITextFieldDelegate { 
 func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if textField == yourSpecificTextFiled{
        if UIPasteboard.general.isKind(of: UIPasteboard.self){
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
  } 
}
```