# Swift: Copy/paste enable and disable for specific fields

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have create username and create password. There is no character limit for username but password is has 8 digit character limit. How to disable the copy/paste only for password field. And also how to filter some characters which are not valid for username.

Comment: FYI, this question has already been answered. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29596043/how-to-disable-pasting-in-a-textfield-in-swift

Comment: @TannerJuby No this question is not answered. The link which you shared is  generic solution to disable copy and paste, but the one which i posted is for how to disable copy paste for specfic field and how to filter the characters.

Comment: @mokshaharish Yes, I understand. I posted an answer below which answers your question. And the "generic solution" that was shared will work for a specific field (i.e. the field that you assign the custom class to). 

If you still don't think it's specific enough (i.e. you would want to use the custom TextField for many different fields) then I suggest creating a boolean such as `pasteable` as a variable in the custom class and setting that to true/false upon initialization of the field. And then use that boolean to disable posting via `canPerformAction`

Comment: @ksav Why is that?

Comment: @TannerJuby https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/21062/preventing-a-user-from-pasting-from-the-clipboard-into-a-mandatory-form-field

Comment: @ksav I would say let the UX designer of the product decide that as there are certainly cases in which you don't want to allow pasting in a field.

Comment: @TannerJuby if you're at the point where you are even considering this feature then chances are that your 'UX designer' already resigned.

Comment: @ksav There are plenty of large scale, very successful, great UX products that I've encountered that don't allow user's to paste a password, financial account number, or other fraud preventative inputs. Don't tell people they can't do something just because your opinion conflicts it.

Answer (score 0):

**For the Copy and Paste Question:**

You will need to create your own TextField class that inherits UITextField and then override the `canPerformAction` delegate method to disable pasting:

```
override func canPerformAction(action: Selector, withSender sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    if action == "paste:" {
        return false
    }        
    return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
}
```

More detailed description: [How to disable Pasting in a TextField in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29596043/how-to-disable-pasting-in-a-textfield-in-swift)

**For the Characters Question:**

Similar concept as above, except you will need to implement the `textFieldDidEndEditing` or `shouldChangeCharactersIn` delegate methods.

`textFieldDidEndEditing` will allow you to evaluate the string in the field AFTER the user has stopped editing that field. Example:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField, reason: UITextFieldDidEndEditingReason) {
    switch textField {
        case usernameTextField:
            // evaluate the `textField.text` for is a valid username
        case passwordTextField:
            // evaluate the `textField.text ` for is a valid password
    }
}
```

`shouldChangeCharactersIn` will allow you to evaluate the string for every keystroke (I prefer using the later when evaluating textfield inputs). Example:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    switch textField {
        case usernameTextField:
            // evaluate the `replacementString` for is a valid username
        case passwordTextField:
            // evaluate the `replacementString` for is a valid password
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Maybe credit the original https://stackoverflow.com/a/29596354/2907715

Comment: @Carpsen90 I did in the original comment

Comment: @Carpsen90 I also don't necessarily consider this a duplicate because there was also a question in there about filtering characters. I consider this question to be about UITextField evaluation/modification in a general sense rather than specifically that single Copy and Paste question.

Comment: this doesn't answer how to prevent pasting for specific fields tho. does `sender` have access to the textfield?

Comment: @frlzjosh yes it does, the `if action === "paste:" return false` does exactly that