# How to remove the option window for selected text in textfield, Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uitextfield

When text is selected/marked in my app this window pops up with different options if the user would want to copy/cut out etc, but I want this window not to be able to pop up at all. Anyone knows how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance, Pontus[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable pasting in a TextField in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29596043/how-to-disable-pasting-in-a-textfield-in-swift)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must create a subclass of your `UITexField` or `UITextView` (or `UILabel`) depending on which one you want to disable the `UIMenu`. 
Then override:

```
func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, 
           withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool
```

And return no for the selectors you want to disable.
If you prefer to disable selection of text in a `UITextView`, you can disable the selection behavior.