# How to disable the copy paste functionality in SkyFloatingLabelTextField in swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate, skyfloatinglabeltextfield

I am using the SkyFloatingLabelTextField class for UITextfield,How can I disable the Copy and paste functionality on this textfiled.

Comment: You can do that by overriding the "canPerformAction" method. Check this answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29596043/how-to-disable-pasting-in-a-textfield-in-swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom class inherited from SkyFloatingLabelTextField class and then assign.

```
class FloatingTextField: SkyFloatingLabelTextField {
    open override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        if action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.paste(_:)) ||
            action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.copy(_:)) {
            return false
        }
        return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
    }
}
```

If you want for the whole project and all textfield add this extension.

```
extension SkyFloatingLabelTextField {
    open override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        if action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.paste(_:)) ||
            action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.copy(_:)) {
            return false
        }
        return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
    }
}
```

Comment: will this work for UItextView as well@Raja Kishan

Comment: @ManishKumar yes

Answer (score 2):

Use this technique for custom textField

```
   class SkyFloatingLabelTextField: UITextField {
        open override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
            if action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.paste(_:)) {
                return false
            }
            return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Already assigned a class SkyfloatingLabelTextField to the UITextField @Jayesh Patel

Comment: Then add it in your SkyFloatingLabelTextField class. i have updated the answer